# Redirect user to another component if it was the first component he visited

Tags: javascript, reactjs, routes, redux

I have a registration form. User fills up all needed data and then he clicks `submit` button and hes being redirected to *confirmation* page.

It's a simple page `/confirm-account` that displays all data he entered so he can make sure he entered everything correctly.

**But**, I don't want user to enter this `/confirm-account` directly from browser, but only after he clicks `submit` button. If he just opened browser and pasted this link and hit enter, it should redirect him to `/register-account`.

My try: (`routes.js`)

```
path: 'confirm-account',
  name: 'confirmAccount',
  indexRoute: { onEnter: (nextState, replace) => {
    if (state doesn\'t have something, I dont know yet) {   <-------------- condition
      replace('/register-account')
    } },
  getComponent(nextState, cb) {
    const importModules = Promise.all([
      import('containers/ConfirmAccount'),
    ]);
```

**Q**: What to use inside the condition?

**Important note**: When submitting, I'm using:

```
this.props.dispatch(push('/confirm-account'));
```

My first thought was to pass some data with that `push` function and check if it's available inside routing file. Or maybe if user is on the `register-account` component, set a specified prop and just check for it's existance inside routes?

Looking forward for any hints. Thank u!

Comment: store the state of the registration in session variable.. when successfull registration you can clear this session variable. 
now if user comes directly to the confirmation component/page. you first check for the session variable and based on that redirect

Comment: @hannadrehman In a session variable? Do you mean in app state? Using e.g. redux?

Comment: i ment browsers ```session storage```  its a ```html5``` web storage medium

Comment: @hannadrehman Hmm, sounds fine, however I bet it isnt the rightest way to fix it. I will try it anyways :) Thanks

Comment: i don't see any other way since ```HTTP``` is a stateless protocol. and ```javascript``` flushes out all the variables on browser refresh, you cannot retain the state of a page without external storage medium. either you can use rest API to get the state or browser storage, or Url Parameters.thats all we can do i guess @patrickkx

Comment: @hannadrehman Agreed, but we can try from the way around. The question is - can we pass some data through `dispatch(push('/'))`? If so, I could pass something when user clicks it, and check if it exists in routes.

Comment: passing anything to router will append it to the url. so it will be possible to directly enter it in the url and it will work. what i suggested earlier you can do same with redux, or app state. all you have to do is pass the props which will be updated when route changes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can test your condition in componentDidMount, and if it's falsy redirect:

```
componentDidMount = () => {
if (!yourCondition) {
  return this.props.history.push({
    pathname: '/register-account'
  });
}
```

}

other solution maybe:

try to redirect like that:

```
import { Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
```

and in the render method use:

```
if (!yourCondition) { return <Redirect to="/register-account" /> }
```

Comment: Tried and it works, but it doesn't work very well. I'm still able to see the content before the redirection occurs :(

Comment: add a return before the  <Redirect /> ?